# mongodb CSFLE -- use dynamic data keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-csfle

We'd like to use mongo's native CSFLE offering (https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/security/client-side-field-level-encryption-guide/), however as per the documentation, it seems like the data key id should be provided ahead of the initialisation of `MongoClient`.

In our use case, we need to use the same schema, however with different data keys, dynamically (e.g. a different data key for each customer in a multitenant architecture)

What is the idiomatic solution for this problem?

Edit: a similar question from mongodb's community forums: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/csfle-with-data-key-per-document/113161

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with explicit encryption, and I believe this is one of the use cases for explicit encryption to begin with.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/reference/client-side-encryption/#explicit-encryption for an example.

Comment: I'm probably asking for too much, but I was hoping to still enjoy the benefits of automatic encryption: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/security-client-side-automatic-json-schema/

Comment: You'd need someone more familiar with the feature than me then to answer that.

Comment: there is no way to use dynamic data keys in autoencryption unfortunately